# Is it possible for a network administrator to detect easily if I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox using NAT mode for networking? If yes how to hide it?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, nat

I want to run linux on virtual box on my computer. How do I run it without getting detected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a NAT Virtual Card, then it should not be detectable outside of the host computer. Virtualbox uses the host's network stack to perform network operations when operating with a NAT Virtual Network Card. This is not the case if you are using a Bridged Network Card, since Virtualbox will bypass the host networking stack in order to expose the virtual machine to the wider network.

To Quote the Virtualbox Manual:

> The disadvantage of NAT mode is that, much like a private network behind a router, the virtual machine is invisible and unreachable from the outside internet; you cannot run a server this way unless you set up port forwarding (described below).
>
> The network frames sent out by the guest operating system are received by VirtualBox's NAT engine, which extracts the TCP/IP data and resends it using the host operating system. To an application on the host, or to another computer on the same network as the host, it looks like the data was sent by the VirtualBox application on the host, using an IP address belonging to the host. VirtualBox listens for replies to the packages sent, and repacks and resends them to the guest machine on its private network.

For further reading on the subject, you can check out [Chapter 6 of the Virtualbox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)